# Kafka-connect FileStreamSourceConnector doesn't produce to a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to create a Kafka-connect connector to sink from an AVRO Topic to a file.

And then restore this file to another topic using kafka-connect.

The sink is working fine, I could see the sink file growing and read the data. But when I try to restore to a new topic, the new topic stays with no data..

And I get no errors, I already reset the offset, I create a new kafka-connect and tried to restore, I create a full new Kafka cluster and always the same, no error on the source connector, but the topic is empty.

Here the output of the source connector config:

```
{
  "name": "restored-exchange-rate-log",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka-schema:8881",
    "file": "/tmp/exchange-rate-log.sink.txt",
    "format.include.keys": "true",
    "source.auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "name": "restored-exchange-rate-log",
    "topic": "restored-exchange-rate-log",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "restored-exchange-rate-log",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

And here the output of the source connecotor status:

```
{
  "name": "restored-exchange-rate-log",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8883"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "id": 0,
      "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8883"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

Here the output of the sink connector config:

```
{
    "name": "bkp-exchange-rate-log",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
    "source.auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "exchange-rate-log",
    "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka-schema:8881",
    "file": "/tmp/exchange-rate-log.sink.txt",
    "format.include.keys": "true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "name": "bkp-exchange-rate-log",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
    },
    "tasks": [
    {
        "connector": "bkp-exchange-rate-log",
        "task": 0
    }
    ],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

Here the output of the sink connector status:

```
{
    "name": "bkp-exchange-rate-log",
    "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8883"
    },
    "tasks": [
    {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "id": 0,
        "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8883"
    }
    ],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

The sink file is working, always growing, but the topic restored-exchange-rate-log is totally empty.

---

Adding more details.

I have tried now to do the "Zalando" way, but we don't use the s3, we are using the FileStream connector.

Here the Sink:

```
{
  "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
  "file": "/tmp/exchange-rate-log.bin",
  "format.include.keys": "true",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "topics": "exchange-rate-log",
  "format": "binary",
  "value.converter": "com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.AlreadyBytesConverter",
  "key.converter": "com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.AlreadyBytesConverter",
  "name": "bkp-exchange-rate-log"
}
```

Here the Source:

```
{
  "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
  "file": "/tmp/exchange-rate-log.bin",
  "format.include.keys": "true",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "format": "binary",
  "topic": "bin-test-exchange-rate-log",
  "value.converter": "com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.AlreadyBytesConverter",
  "key.converter": "com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.AlreadyBytesConverter",
  "name": "restore-exchange-rate-log"
}
```

The sink connector looks fine, the sink generated this file /tmp/exchange-rate-log.bin and is increasing, but the Source (Restore) is getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: bin-test-exchange-rate-log error: Not a byte array! [B@761db301
    at com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.AlreadyBytesConverter.fromConnectData(AlreadyBytesConverter.java:22)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Out of interest, what are you building here? Using files is generally an anti-pattern, particularly if you already have one topic and want to write to another. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html might be worth a look

Comment: You'll want to use bytearray converters to dump and restore. For example, here's an example of doing it with S3. https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/backing-up-kafka-zookeeper/index.html?gh_src=4n3gxh1

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I'm trying to build a backup from my current topics, because of this I'm using txt files to be able to versioning and recover for a certain period of time.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have done using the bytearray.
The sink file has now this kind of content:
[B@2e2f84bd
[B@6f34b60d
[B@254544f8

But when I try to restore.. same thing no data on the topic. Maybe the Zalando way doesn't work with avro?

Comment: I've used the Zalando one fine for recovering Avro... In fact, binary data doesn't care if there are Avro, integers, strings, etc data... Kafka just stores bytes, so if you want to backup and recover a topic (without worrying about serialization), then it must be binary, which is not intended to be human-readable

Comment: Thanks, @cricket_007, I believe I was failing before because I was using the ByteArray from apache and not the AlreadyBytesConverter from spredfast.

I have added more details to the question.
But basically, I get this error now "DataException: bin-test-exchange-rate-log error: Not a byte array! [B@761db301"

Should this converter work with FileStreamSource? Or was built to work only with s3 buckets?

Comment: FileStreamSource expects text, not binary, if I recall correctly (and the Apache docs even say File Connectors are only **examples** to build your own connectors, not to really be relied on otherwise)... And the "already bytes" one has the same source code as the  ByteArrayConverter. Again, I don't think either of these connectors will work for your purposes. I'm just pointing out that you must use binary formats, not any extra serialization.

Comment: In fact, I might recommended some other tool entirely like Streamsets or Nifi, which are more feature complete

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand, thanks for your help, I was trying to just create a backup like dump and restore. Is weird that I need another cluster or another product like (Nifi, Streamsets) just to do a backup. There is a way to export an avro topic to a binary file and then restore it?

Comment: `console-consumer` will dump binary, sure, and the console-producer can be configured to have `--value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.serialization.ByteArraySerializer`, or something similar to that, I believe, however it might still try to parse the data as UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Regarding using a second cluster with other tools, it's not "necessary". I was just pointing out those give you more options.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate the "Dump" of a topic using the kafka-avro-console-consumer. We are using SSL + Schema Registry.

Here is the command line to be able to generate the dump of a topic:

```
tpc=exchange-rate-log
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=. -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=." \
kafka-avro-console-consumer \
  --from-beginning --bootstrap-server $CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS \
  --property schema.registry.url=$CONNECT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL \
  --topic $tpc --consumer-property security.protocol=SSL \
  --consumer-property ssl.truststore.location=/etc/ssl/kafkaproducer.truststore.jks \
  --consumer-property ssl.truststore.password=$MYPASS \
  --consumer-property ssl.keystore.location=/etc/ssl/kafkaproducer.keystore.jks \
  --consumer-property ssl.keystore.password=$MYPASS \
  --consumer-property ssl.key.password=$MYPASS \
  --property "key.separator=::-::" \
  --property "schema.id.separator=::_::" \
  --property print.schema.ids=true \
  --timeout-ms 15000 \
  --property "print.key=true" \
  --key-deserializer "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" > $tpc.dump
```

But I didn't find a way how to import it back using the kafka-avro-console-producer, because it doesn't work with non-avro keys.
With this dump file, I could write a python producer that reads that file and restore the topic back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that Connect File connectors are a good use case for this.

Plus, the Avro converter won't dump the file in a reproducible format. It'll look like `Struct{field=value}`

If you really wanted to dump to a file, just do `kafka-avro-console-consumer`, include the key, pass the `--key-deserializer` as the string one, then write it out using `> file.txt`

To recover, you can try to use the Avro console producer, but there is no string serializer property, so the keys will need to be quoted, I believe to be passed to the JSON parser

You can test like so

```
echo '"1"|{"data":value"}'  > kafka-avro-console-producer...
```

(need to set the `key.separator` property, as well)

And doing a file would look like

```
kafka-avro-console-producer...  < file.txt
```

---

For this to work in the case your whole Kafka Cluster goes away, and you are left with just this file, though, then you'll also need to take a backup of your Avro schema (because the Registry `_schemas` topic is gone)

Comment: looks like is not possible to use the kafka-avro-console-producer with a non-avro key.

If I execute the kafka-avro-console-producer with the  --property "parse.key=true" it will require the key.schema.

I was able to generate the "dump" including the key, avro message and the schema id from the schema registry.

But to produce (import the file back), doesn't work without the key.schema

Comment: Right. Personally, I have re-written the console producer to achieve this. Kafka Connect could also work, but not using one of the included ones